# I can't seem to splice an array from a reference in Perl

Tags: arrays, perl

So I am passing an array reference into a function to clear out certain array elements:

The code is as follows:

```
if($notes->[$x] !~ /[^CF]/)
{
    print "$notes->[$x]\n";
    splice (@{$notes}), $x, 1;          
}
```

If I comment out the splice line, the loop works fine showing me each $x element of the array.  But if I do not comment out the splice comment, it all fails. It won't print out the $x element nor will the splice command work.

> Use of uninitialized value in pattern match (m//) at
>   /var/www/cgi-bin/Funx.pm line 130.
>
> Use of uninitialized value in
>   concatenation (.) or string at /var/www/cgi-bin/Funx.pm line 132.

Totally unsure as to what's going on here.  I can understand my splice line not being the correct syntax.  But why it affects the line above it I don't.

Any insight would be appreciated.

Comment: Try `splice @$notes, $x, 1`.

Comment: @HåkonHægland  No, still won't work, and adds a new error on top of the other ones.

'splice() offset past end of array at /var/www/cgi-bin/Funx.pm line 133.'

Comment: You have not adequately demonstrated your problem. Please read [mcve], then fix your question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First of all

```
splice(@{$notes}), $x, 1;
```

should be

```
splice(@{$notes}, $x, 1);
```

That's not the error you asked about, but it's the only one you showed.

---

The error leading to the error message you did obtain is likely an incorrect loop. I believe you are using something along the lines of

```
for (@$notes)
```

or

```
for (0..$#$notes)
```

The first is buggy because you are not allowed to add or remove elements from an array over which you are iterating.

The second is buggy because it will execute the loop body as many times as the array had elements originally, so you'll end up looping too many times.

Comment: It works now.  Would love to know why you can do '@splice, 3, 1;' but that if it's a reference you need to use parenthesis `splice (@{$reference}, $x, 1);`

Comment: @SergioD.Caplan: *Would love to know why you can do `@splice, 3, 1;` but that if it's a reference you need to use parenthesis `splice (@{$reference}, $x, 1);`* You don't need to do that `splice @{$reference}, $x, 1` works fine too.